# Sinch Web to iPhone Calling

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, web, sinch

I am working on an app in which i want to received the video call from web, iPhone to iPhone is working but web to iPhone is not working, getting this. I am using the sample code provided by sinch.

> **Browser Chrome** -> Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
>
> **End cause**: NO_ANSWER

```
(audio_device_generic.cc:17): BuiltInAECIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:27): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:37): BuiltInNSIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:17): BuiltInAECIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:27): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:37): BuiltInNSIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:17): BuiltInAECIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:27): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
    (audio_device_generic.cc:37): BuiltInNSIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: I found a way how to fix as in

web sinch does send voip push notification, rather it automatically make a call by calling ‘didReceiveIncomingCall’, so I send voip push to iOS and in response, I make a call from web

Comment: Thank you Salman500. Can you please share sample code.